# HTML/CSS Div Table (3x2) - Change Text align to top

Tags: html, css

i got following problem:
I want the text to be displayed in a table of 3x2, which it does.
But the text in my second and third column is aligned to the bottom, because they are smaller than the text in my first column.
How do i set all of the texts to start at the top?

```css
.row {
    margin: 0% 15% 0% 15%;
}

.col {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="tab">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p>Title</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p>Title</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p>Title</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p>12321312312312</p>
                <p>12321312312312</p>
                <p>12321312312312</p>
                <p>12321312312312</p>
                <p>12321312312312</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p>12321312312312</p>
                <p>12321312312312</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p>12321312312312</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?  to me it seems like you not intending to actually sue it for data but layout. In that case use a css-grid. Way easier with less hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top;` Like this:

```css
.row {
    margin: 0% 15% 0% 15%;
}

.col {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="tab">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p>Title</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p>Title</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p>Title</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p>12321312312312</p>
                <p>12321312312312</p>
                <p>12321312312312</p>
                <p>12321312312312</p>
                <p>12321312312312</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p>12321312312312</p>
                <p>12321312312312</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p>12321312312312</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine. That you very much

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

Add vertical-align to top in .col.

```
.col {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be the sue of the right tool for such task: CSS-Grid.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Title</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Title</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Title</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>12321312312312</p>
  <p>12321312312312</p>
  <p>12321312312312</p>
  <p>12321312312312</p>
  <p>12321312312312</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>12321312312312</p>
  <p>12321312312312</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>12321312312312</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a simple and slight redesign, using grid, no vertical align needed

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
            title
            <div class="column">
                <p>12321312312312</p>
                <p>12321312312312</p>
                <p>12321312312312</p>
                <p>12321312312312</p>
                <p>12321312312312</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            title
            <div class="column">
                <p>12321312312312</p>
                <p>12321312312312</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            title
            <div class="column">
                <p>12321312312312</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anthony_718/pen/JjRRpoM